# How to fix mismatched csrf authenticity tokens in rails devise forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, csrf, authenticity-token

[image]

If I am understanding this correctly the input authenticity token should be matching the value above in the head element.

When submitting the devise sign up form I get a 422 Unprocessible Entity error.

I did delete my `master.key` and re-ran `rails credentitals:edit` to regenerate the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` and `SECRET_KEY_BASE`.

I believe the issue here is since these values are not matching, the form is not being processed resulting in the devise User not being created.

Answer (score 0):

Delete config/master.key and config/credentials.yml.enc. Then run rails credentials:edit and it will make a new key and encrypted credentials file. Don't forget to restart the rails server.